i am getting "undefined reference" error while i am going to defination it is there in arduino ide
I'm trying to generate keys for encoding and decoding using the Kyber API in an Arduino project, but I'm encountering a compilation error. My code includes the api.h header and attempts to call crypto_kem_keypair, crypto_kem_enc, and crypto_kem_dec. The functions seem to be linked correctly in the code editor, but I get the following error during compilation:
undefined reference to `crypto_kem_keypair(unsigned char*, unsigned char*)'
undefined reference to `crypto_kem_enc(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, unsigned char const*)'
undefined reference to `crypto_kem_dec(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*)'

How can I resolve this issue?
Here is a snippet of my code for reference:
#include "api.h" // Include the Kyber API header

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); // Start serial communication for debugging

  // Kyber 1024 key exchange example
  uint8_t pk[CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
  uint8_t sk[CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBYTES];
  uint8_t ct[CRYPTO_CIPHERTEXTBYTES];
  uint8_t ss[CRYPTO_BYTES];
  uint8_t ss_dec[CRYPTO_BYTES];

  // Generate keypair
  crypto_kem_keypair(pk, sk);
  Serial.println("Keypair generated.");

  // Encapsulate
  crypto_kem_enc(ct, ss, pk);
  Serial.println("Encapsulation done.");

  // Decapsulate
  crypto_kem_dec(ss_dec, ct, sk);
  Serial.println("Decapsulation done.");

  // Verify shared secret
  bool valid = true;
  for (int i = 0; i < CRYPTO_BYTES; i++) {
    if (ss[i] != ss_dec[i]) {
      valid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (valid) {
    Serial.println("Shared secrets match.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Shared secrets do not match.");
  }
}

void loop() {}


I have verified that the api.h file is included correctly, and I believe the necessary function implementations are present. Any advice on resolving the linker errors would be greatly appreciated.

Hello, how are you compiling this ? With gcc you can include libraries using -l flag for example, add an example of your compilation so we can help you better ;)

i am compiling it using arduino ide.
i have imported all required files from git rep to arduino ide.

Could you share compilation logs ? It's probably a linking issue in your arduino IDE, do you have access to the gcc command parameters to add the library using -l ?

compilation text is too big so how can i share

You could use pastebin ;)

Thanks for your help I solved the problem it was because of I was using cpp file as a main but other files was c which contains definations so I have to add define cpp in all header files to get output

Great to hear, welcome even tho you figured it out yourself
